# how to get similarity score using Matching matrix

Tags: python, matrix, keras, similarity

I want to get similarity score by using this architecture and want to know some python code, but I get error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

[image]

Here is my architecture:

[image]

The model code is as follows:

```
input_shape=(300,128)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64,3, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape = 
input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100))
model.summary()
```

[image]

I run my model with the following code:

```
def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape, stddev=0.01))


 num_of_filters = 100
 similarity_matrix = init_weights([num_of_filters, num_of_filters])
 mat = K.dot(l, similarity_matrix)
 similarity = tf.math.reduce_sum(mat * r, axis=1)
 similarity = tf.reshape(similarity, [-1, 1])

 pairwise_feature =layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([l,r,similarity])
 siamese_net = Model(inputs= [left_input,right_input],outputs = 
 prediction)
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding code as text instead of image if possible

Comment: i post it now!!